# How to keep redis connection open when reading from reactive API

Tags: redis, reactive-programming, spring-data-redis, lettuce

I am continuously listening on redis streams using the spring reactive api(using lettuce driver). I am using a standalone connection. It seems like the reactor's event loop opens a new connection every time it reads the messages instead of keeping the connection open. I see a lot of TIME_WAIT ports in my machine when i run my program. Is this normal? Is there a way to let lettuce know to re-use the connection instead of reconnecting every time?

This is my code:

```
StreamReceiver<String, MapRecord<String, String, String>> receiver = StreamReceiver.create(factory);
return receiver
    .receive(Consumer.from(keyCacheStreamsConfig.getConsumerGroup(), keyCacheStreamsConfig.getConsumer()),
        StreamOffset.create(keyCacheStreamsConfig.getStreamName(), ReadOffset.lastConsumed()))//
    // flatMap reads 256 messages by default and processes them in the given scheduler
    .flatMap(record -> Mono.fromCallable(() -> consumer.consume(record)).subscribeOn(Schedulers.boundedElastic()))//
    .doOnError(t -> {
      log.error("Error processing.", t);
      streamConnections.get(nodeName).setDirty(true);
    })//
    .onErrorContinue((err, elem) -> log.error("Error processing message. Continue listening."))//
    .subscribe();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the spring-data-redis library re-uses the connection only if the poll timeout is set to '0' in the stream receiver options and pass it as the second argument in `StreamReceiver.create(factory, options)`. Figured by looking into spring-data-redis' source code.